# Illegal reflective access operation warning for java.io.OutputStreamWriter.flushBuffer()

Tags: spring, java-11

Using 2.1.2.RELEASE with OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM AdoptOpenJDK (build 11.0.2+9, mixed mode) the following warnings are printed during application startup which I would not expect according to the closed spring issue
[#22032](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/22032). Is this a different issue? Can I do anything myself to fix that? 2.1.2.RELEASE is using spring-framework.version 5.1.4.RELEASE. Issue #22032 seems to have been added to the 5.1.3 milestone already.

```
2019-02-04 14:52:39.534 DEBUG 4856 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy          : Method [void java.io.OutputStreamWriter.flushBuffer() throws java.io.IOException] is package-visible across different ClassLoaders and cannot get proxied via CGLIB: Declare this method as public or protected if you need to support invocations through the proxy.
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access using Lookup on org.springframework.cglib.core.ReflectUtils (file:/C:/Users/myself/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-core/5.1.4.RELEASE/spring-core-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar) to class java.io.OutputStreamWriter
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of org.springframework.cglib.core.ReflectUtils
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
```

With the setting "--illegal-access=warn" the following is printed during application launch.

```
2019-02-04 15:02:06.471 DEBUG 6804 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy          : Method [void java.io.OutputStreamWriter.flushBuffer() throws java.io.IOException] is package-visible across different ClassLoaders and cannot get proxied via CGLIB: Declare this method as public or protected if you need to support invocations through the proxy.
WARNING: Illegal reflective access using Lookup on org.springframework.cglib.core.ReflectUtils (file:/C:/Users/myself/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-core/5.1.4.RELEASE/spring-core-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar) to class java.io.OutputStreamWriter
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by org.springframework.cglib.core.ReflectUtils (file:/C:/Users/myself/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-core/5.1.4.RELEASE/spring-core-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar) to method java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(java.lang.String,byte[],int,int,java.security.ProtectionDomain)
2019-02-04 15:02:06.484 DEBUG 6804 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'byteArrayStreamInDokumentinhalt'
WARNING: Illegal reflective access using Lookup on org.springframework.cglib.core.ReflectUtils (file:/C:/Users/myself/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-core/5.1.4.RELEASE/spring-core-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar) to class java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream
```

Comment: I suspect by not using devtools.

Comment: Actually using devtools. But even without that dependency the same warnings appear.